# How can I use JQuery in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn how to make extensions, and I'm starting off very basic.  I keep getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "Testing",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.min.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["run.js"]
    }
}
```

The JQuery file is properly named and located inside of the extension folder.  This is the 'run.js' script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("document loaded");
})
```

How can I fix this so that I can properly use JQuery?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `content_scripts/matches` property, you're limiting your jQuery to only load if the current URL matches `http://www.google.com/*`. Change it to match all domains:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "Testing",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*"],
            "js": ["jquery.min.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["run.js"]
    }
}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration):

> Required. Specifies which pages this content script will be injected
>   into. See Match Patterns for more details on the syntax of these
>   strings and Match patterns and globs for information on how to exclude
>   URLs.

**OR**, you can add it to your existing background scripts:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "run.js"]
}
```